# visual studio inline javascript obfuscator

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Does anyone know a plugin or tool that would obfuscate my inline javascript (in script block) in my .aspx pages when publishing? It wouldn't do any harm, if the plugin also removed xml comments/html comments, empty lines and and so on.

Its no security question ;) I just don't want users to be able to see comments and read the code straight away - and maybe have everything look a bit more pretty in the end.

Comment: doesnt aspx pages provide a server-side comment format ?